# Android image resize after camera intent callback

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

my first question here! I have a problem with a piece of code that starts a camera intent with the extra output options and then on activity result tries to resize that image. what is happening is that a nullpointer exception gets thrown in the resize function at the callback.

The original large picture is still saved on the file system, as I can access that from the filesystem.

The original camera jpeg is 2560x1920 in size and the phone in use is a google nexus one.

**I have no clear idea asto why the resize is not working, anyone have any insight?**

Here's some code:

The takePicture function that also creates the dummy file:

```
        public boolean takePicture( ) {

            Log.e(TAG, "takePicture interface function");
            String FileUri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/samples/";
            File file = new File(FileUri,"picture"+ pictureNumber +".jpg");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            Log.e(TAG, "intent started");
            return true;
        }
```

The on activity result callback function:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

        // handle the camera request returns and handle back button in camera.

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED ) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,"Canceled, no picture taken.", 1000);
            toast.show();
            return;
           }

        else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) { 

            Log.e(TAG, "Camera intent return");

            Bitmap scaledphoto = null;
            int height = 300;
            int width = 300;    

            Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( APP_DATA_PATH + "/samples/picture" + pictureNumber + ".jpg" );
            Log.e(TAG, "Picture fetched");

            scaledphoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, height, width, true);


            Log.e(TAG, "Picture scaled");

            saveImageToFile(scaledphoto, "picture" + pictureNumber + ".jpg");


            Log.e(TAG, "Scaled picture saved");

            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:pictureTaken(\""+ pictureLoc + "\")");

            pictureNumber++;
```

And here's the LogCat:

```
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure     delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} to activity {test.test/test.test.CameraIntentTestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 14:59:13.496: E/AndroidRuntime(6130):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:432)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( APP_DATA_PATH + "/samples/picture" + pictureNumber + ".jpg" );
```

To

```
  Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

Comment: The pictures I get with this method all seem to be mega blurry as if upscaled from a smaller bitmap, whereas the pictures that are saved straight to the folder with extra output seem to be full resolution jpegs. It works, but does not seem to be the best way to get medium resolution jpegs that i would like, ie 400x400.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the image size is just the reason why its failing, as searching through stackoverflow I found a couple of guys with the same problem. Thanks for the tip!